# FreeBSD specify partial directory names to search using find

Tags: linux, unix, find, freebsd

I have the following directory:

```
/usr/smac/results/june/
```

In this directory I have a lot of directories. I'm only interested in the ones that start with 'ceg' e.g.

```
ceg20160611234
gfd20160611493
ceg20160611543
ceg20160612193
flc20160612873
```

Each of these has the following:

run1/logfile
run2/logfile
run3/logfile
etc.

I know how to use the 'find' command to search for a string within each logfile i.e.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name logfile -exec egrep -l 'passed' {} \;
```

However this will search all files i.e.

```
ceg20160611234/run1/logfile
ceg20160611234/run2/logfile
ceg20160611234/run3/logfile
[...]
gfd20160611493/run1/logfile
gfd20160611493/run2/logfile
[...]
ceg20160611543/run1/logfile
ceg20160611543/run2/logfile
[...]
ceg20160612193/run1/logfile
ceg20160612193/run2/logfile
[...]
flc20160612873/run1/logfile
flc20160612873/run2/logfile
[...]
```

I want to minimise the search to only search the directories starting with 'ceg' e.g.

```
ceg20160611234/run1/logfile
ceg20160611234/run2/logfile
ceg20160611234/run3/logfile
[...]
ceg20160611543/run1/logfile
ceg20160611543/run2/logfile
[...]
ceg20160612193/run1/logfile
ceg20160612193/run2/logfile
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` command as

```
find ceg* -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "logfile" -exec egrep -l 'passed' {} \;
```

will do the above operation on the directory names starting with `ceg*` and performs the `egrep` on the files named `logfile` inside those directories.

Answer (score 0):

find ./ceg* -maxdepth 2 -type f -name logfile -exec egrep -l 'passed' {} \;

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

find /usr/smac/results/june/ -name 'ceg*'

Basically, the argument to -name supports the shell special characters, such as "*" and "?"; be sure, however, to quote it ('') so they get passed to the find command instead of being expanded by the shell.